# How can I use imply an OR query on an B-Tree?

Tags: indexing, b-tree

I want to use b-tree for index, but I can't think out an solution for OR query.

For OR query, I mean something like
select * from table where id between 1 and 5 OR id between 10 and 15;

if I use id as the key in the b-tree, than how can I do query like above on the b-tree?

when search through the b-tree, assume that the key that are smaller than 6 and bigger than 6 is on different sub-trees, than when the search path go through the sub-tree that contaions the key that are smaller than 6, id that between 1 and 5 can be retrived, but what about id that between 10 and 15?

Do I have to use the b+tree,and when I found the key which points to id 1 , I just keep scan through the leaf nodes one by one until I found the key which points to id 15?
Is it bad solution for this kind of query:
select * from table where id between 1 and 5 OR id between 10000000 and 10000005???

Or is there any other solutions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

An OR operation implies that two searches need to be done, and the results combined.

Comment: Do you mean I have to do the search on the b-tree twice to get the result?

So what about an AND operation?
Just change the query to:
select * from table where id between 1 and 5 AND id between 10000000 and 10000005

How about this query? Also do the search twice? 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically, yes, do two searches for both OR and AND. You can of course get much fancier as Markus suggests below, but that is more a matter of how complex you want to make your query engine.

Answer (score 1):

The *OR* keyword is a common problem. From index perspective it is usually best to do two lookups (e.g., like a UNION).

However, exceptions exist. Your first example (id between 1 and 5 OR id between 10 and 15) might be best done in one index lookup from 1 to 15, discarding the values 6-9. However, that depends on the data volume! You second example (between 1 and 5 OR id between 10000000 and 10000005) doesn't look to be a good candidate for that approach. However, it depends on the number of rows, not on the number of the id's.

Regarding *AND*: your example is a contradiction (id between 1 and 5 AND id between 10000000 and 10000005), the query will not return any rows. Some optimizers are able to "see" that.

*AND* conditions on different columns are to be solved with concatenated indexes.

Have a look at my Web-Book [Use The Index, Luke!](http://Use-The-Index-Luke.com/) for further details.